# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined (Todo list application )

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom, frontend

So I am learning and practising Javascript. The code below actually works it renders the list of TODOs when you write in filter Todos. The problem is that I cannot understand this  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined when I use LowerCase and includes method.

**The HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something to do" id="new-todo-text">
    <button id='add-todo'>Add Todo</button>
    <input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder ='Filter todos'>
    <div id='todos'></div>
    <script src ='todo-experiment.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Javascript file**

```
const todos = [{},{
  activity: 'order',
  completed: true
},{
  activity: 'clean',
  completed: false
}, {
  activity: 'Buy',
  completed: true
}, {
  activity: 'Do',
  completed: false 
}, {
  activity: 'Excercise',
  completed: true 
}]

const filters = {
  searchtext: ''
}


const renderTodos = function(todos, filters){
       const filteredTodos = todos.filter(function (todo){
         return todo.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchtext.toLowerCase())
       })

       const incompleteTodos = todos.filter(function(todo){
         return !todo.completed
       })

       document.querySelector('#todo').innerHTML = ''


       const p = document.querySelector('h2')
       summary.textContent = `You have ${incompleteTodos.length} todos left`
       document.querySelector('body').appendChild(p)

       todos.forEach(function (todo){
         const p =document.createElement('p')
         p.textContent = todo.text
         document.querySelector('body').appendChild(p)
       })
      }

      renderTodos(todos, filters)

document.querySelector('#add-todo').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('Add a new todo ...')

})
document.querySelector('#add-todo').addEventListener('input', function(e){
  console.log(e.target.value)

})

document.querySelector('#search-text').addEventListener('input', function(e){
  filters.searchtext = e.target.value
  renderTodos(todos, filters)
})
```

Comment: your todos array doesn't have an todo object with a title so `return todo.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchtext.toLowerCase())` causes error

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing a property called `title` on a `todo` object:

```
todo.title.toLowerCase()
```

But they have no such property:

```
{
    activity: 'order',
    completed: true
}
```

Perhaps you meant to reference `activity`:

```
todo.activity.toLowerCase()
```

---

Note also that the first `todo` in the list has no properties at all:

```
{}
```

That's likely to cause the same error as well.  You might at least give it an empty activity:

```
{ activity: '' }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` almost ALWAYS means that a property on an object is not set, and it means that right now too.

You're running `todo.title.toLowerCase()` on a todo list looking like

```js
const todos = [{},{
  activity: 'order',
  completed: true
},{
  activity: 'clean',
  completed: false
}, 
// and some more
]
```

In this list none of the todos have a `title`-property (the first one has **no** properties). So when you try to run `todo.title.toLowerCase()`, you're running `undefined.toLowerCase()`, which doesn't make sense.

To fix the problem, you have to choices:

1. Make sure every todo-item has the `title`-property
2. Make the `title`-property optional by running `(todo.title || '').toLowerCase()`, which makes it fall back to `''` if `todo.title` is `undefined`, `null` or another [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

### Good luck!

---

Edit later the same day: I just learned that if you want to run functions on optional properties (like title in our case), you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```js
const a = [{foo: 'bar'}, {}]

a.map(obj => obj.foo?.toLowerCase() ?? '-') // ['bar', '-']
```